# How can I convert a property name to a framework element in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, xaml

This is the code in C#:

```
 public static FrameworkElement GetFocusedOn(UIElement element)
    {
        return (FrameworkElement)element.GetValue(FocusedOnProperty);
    }
```

I'm trying to write it in VB.NET but it does not cast to a FrameworkElement. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work provided that the `FocusedOn` property returns a `FrameworkElement`:

```
Public Shared Function GetFocusedOn(ByVal element As UIElement) As FrameworkElement
    Return CType(element.GetValue(FocusedOnProperty), FrameworkElement)
End Function
```

You want to use the [TryCast operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/trycast-operator).